# How to get list data on Firebase android and processing data on oncreate function in Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question, I've tried several methods but they haven't worked; I'm hoping that everyone will assist me.

I'd want to obtain a list of data from Firebase (Figure 1). However, when I use it in the onCreate function (Figure 2), it becomes much slower, and I am unable to obtain the log data (Figure 3).
Such, how do I obtain the list data and alter it so that I can hide, reveal, or deactivate a feature?

Everyone, thank you for taking the time to read this.

My code here:

```
class FirebaseDatabaseManager


    class FirebaseDatabaseManager() : ChildEventListener {

    private lateinit var reference: DatabaseReference
    private var productIds: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()


    fun initDatabaseReference(key: String): FirebaseDatabaseManager {
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(key)
        return this
    }

    fun pushData(value: String) {
        reference.push().setValue(value, completionListener)
    }

    private var completionListener =
        DatabaseReference.CompletionListener { error, ref ->
            if (error == null) {
                Logger.d("completionListener", "onComplete pushed.!")
            }
        }

    fun loadListData() {
        reference.addChildEventListener(this)
    }

    fun getListData(): MutableList<String> {
        return productIds
    }

    override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
        val value = snapshot.value.toString()
        productIds.add(value)
        Logger.d("FirebaseDatabaseManager_Main",
            "onChildAdded: productIds.size ------  ${productIds.size}")
    }

    override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
    }

    override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val value = snapshot.value.toString()
        productIds.remove(value)
    }

    override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    private lateinit var productIds: MutableList<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
     
        productIds = ArrayList()

        FirebaseDatabaseManager().initDatabaseReference(keyId).loadListData()
        productIds = FirebaseDatabaseManager().getListData()

        Logger.d("MainActivity", "productIds   ------ $productIds")
    }
}
```

This is log when run app:
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Thank for your mention, I have been edited it.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Yeah. Run code without error, but code doesn't work the way i expect. I can not get value of last index on firebase to set into a textview, and disable button update when it already on my database.